# Tabularx "Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}"

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have two problems at once. Firstly, I get the error "Undefined control sequence". I have often read that this is due to the missing `\usepackage{booktabs}`. I don't use any commands from the package, but I added it anyway. However, the error still occurs. Am I still missing a package?

I am very grateful for any tips!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \small
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}            
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|p{.15\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}}
                Merkmal &  & Provinzen &  & Gesamtmenge\\ \hline 
                & Nord-West Provinz \linebreak (n = 374) & Copperbelt \linebreak (n = 394) & Ost Provinz \linebreak (n = 355) & n = 1123 \\
                \hline \hline
                Gesamtgröße der Landnutzungsfläche (ha) & 3.0 (3.5) & 4.7 (8.4) & 2.0 (1.6) & 3.3 (5.5) \\
                Gesamtes Einkommen des Haushaltes (Zambesische Kwacha (ZMW)\footnote{bei der Erhebung 1 USD = 10.13 ZMW}) & 9253.4 \linebreak (6579.7) & 13528.7 \linebreak(13841.2) & 59133.8 \linebreak(3653.8) & 9697.7\linebreak (97770.2)\\
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the name of the command is `\footnote` not `\footnode`.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. How dumb :D

Comment: Recreate the error and then open the log-file. It should show you exactly the name of the undefined command.

Comment: It was also the wrong command \footnote. Thanks a lot. In the futher I going to take a closer look to the log-file. It really helps.

Comment: if you use texstudio and were confused by its completely unhelpful display of the error message, do contact them and ask them to fix it, it's been an open requst for _years_ https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: Off-topic: don't use the obsolete `ngerman` package. Instead, run `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to think about giving your table a more attractive, open "look". One way of doing so would be to omit all vertical lines and to actually use the macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule` -- instead of `\hline` and `\hline\hline`.

You could also choose the `c` column type for the four data columns instead of `\p{0.15\textwidth`, thus assigning far more space to the first column.

You may also want to employ the `threeparttable` package and its very flexible `\tnote` directives and `tablenotes` environment to typeset the table-related footnotes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %% that's the deafult nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}X cccc @{}}
     \toprule
     Merkmal & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Provinzen} & \mytab{Gesamt-\\ menge} \\ 
     \cmidrule(lr){2-4} 
     & Nord-West  & Copperbelt & Ost & \\
     & ($n = 374$) & ($n = 394$) & ($n = 355$) &  ($n = 1123$) \\
     \midrule 
     Gesamtgröße der Landnutzungsfläche (ha) 
     & 3.0 (3.5) & 4.7 (8.4) & 2.0 (1.6) & 3.3 (5.5) \\
     \addlinespace
     Gesamtes Einkommen des Haushaltes, Zambesische Kwacha (ZMW)\tnote{a} 
     & \mytab{ 9253.4 \\  (6579.7)} & \mytab{13528.7 \\ (13841.2)}
     & \mytab{59133.8 \\  (3653.8)} & \mytab{ 9697.7 \\ (97770.2)} \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] bei der Erhebung 1 USD = 10.13 ZMW
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```